# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) Value and Select

Tags: mysql

Is it not possible to do an Operation like this in an SQL Statement?

```
INSERT INTO ships (user_id,construction_time, fleet_id, template_id, experience, hitpoints,unit_4,rof)
        VALUES (11, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), (-5002), (SELECT id, value_9, value_5, min_unit_4, rof FROM ship_templates WHERE ship_torso >2  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy one table data to another :-

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Try this:-

```
INSERT INTO ships (ser_id,construction_time, fleet_id, template_id, experience, hitpoints,unit_4,rof) 
SELECT '11',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),(-5002),id, value_9, value_5, min_unit_4, rof FROM ship_templates WHERE ship_torso >2  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```